# How find asymptote for this function?

Tags: limits

I have function and I need find asymptote.

$ y = 2 \cdot x - \tan(x) $

I try  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{y\over x}$ and get $2$

What do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\:R\in\Bbb R^+\;$ there exists $\;|x|>R\;$ such that your function isn't defined at $\;x\;$ and thus the function isn't defined for $\;x\to\pm\infty\;$, which of course means the function cannot have non-vertical asymptotes.

On the other hand, at each point of the form $\;x=\frac\pi2+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , the function has a vertical asymptote because of that tangent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

the domain of $\tan x$:

$$\{x\in \mathbb R:\pi\left(n+\frac 1 2\right)<x<\pi\left(n+\frac 3 2\right)\quad n\in \mathbb Z\}$$